# PyQt Matplotlib colour control

Tags: colors, matplotlib, widget, pyqt

Writing in Python 2.7 using pyQt 4.8.5:

How may I alter the background and graph-area (foreground?) of a Matplotlib widget? I would like to make the background of the graph widget 'light gray' (same as the background colour of the GUI), and I would like to make the graph-area (see below) black.

I'm new to GUI programming with pyQt and would like to achieve this:
[image]

my code:

```
self.ui.graph.axes.clear()
self.ui.graph.axes.hold(True)
self.ui.graph.axes.plot(self.Value,'r-')
self.ui.graph.axes.grid()
self.ui.graph.draw()
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
ax = self.ui.graph.axes
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('k')
self.ui.graph.set_facecolor('none')
```

Comment: Note that graph is an instance of matplotlib.figure.Figure

Comment: Been looking for this for so long, thanks! Didn't know "none" is a way to make it transparent :)

Answer (score 0):

This did only partly work for me. The two first lines worked fine but the last did not work. The error I got was: 
AttributeError: 'MatplotlibWidget' object has no attribute 'set_facecolor'

The solution was to add figure to the code:

```
ax = self.ui.graph.axes
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('k')
self.ui.graph.figure.set_facecolor('none')
```

An interesting note is that I had been trying to solve this problem by using setPalette() but this didn't work until the facecolor was set to 'none' then suddenly all the changes I had made to the palette showed up.